# Node.js connection sessions

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js server that pretty much runs a child process and sends the stdout from the process to connected clients via sockets. It is working just fine but when a client disconnects I cannot close the childprocess due to the var being outside the scope. Here is my sample code

```
var sys = require('sys'),
        ws = require('./ws');



var server = ws.createServer(function (socket) {
        socket.addListener("connect", function (resource) {
                var counter = 0;

                sys.puts("client connected from " + resource);

                var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, tail = spawn('app');
                sys.puts("Spawned child pid: "+ tail.pid);

                tail.stdout.addListener('data', function(data) {
                     socket.write(JSON.stringify(data));
                });

        })

        socket.addListener("close", function () {
                //
                // need to access the tail var here!!!
                //


                sys.puts("quit");
        })
})

server.listen(3656)
```

In my close listener I need to access the tail variable so I can kill the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `tail` declaration one level up, from `onConnect` to `createServer`, since it is still the same instance:

```
ws.createServer(function(socket){
    var tail;
    socket.addListener("connect", function(resource){
        tail = spawn("app");
        ...
    });
    socket.addListener("close", function(){
        if(tail)
            tail = null;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks! I tried that and it wasn't working before.. so I must of done something wrong